# syncdb not adding fixtures in 3rd party project

Tags: django, django-syncdb, django-fixtures

I've written a pretty simple Django application called [django-locality](http://github.com/rfkrocktk/django-locality) which takes the headache out of working with countries and territories. It provides a lot of initial data for countries and territories. I just the 0.1 release up to PyPI, and installed it in my project which I'm currently working on. (I basically created it out of a need I found in my original project.)

When I ran `syncdb`, however, it didn't install any of my fixtures from `locality`. In the output, it printed "No fixtures found," and no rows were added to the database, though the tables were generated. Is there a reason why Django is missing my initial data? My data lives at `locality/fixtures/initial_data.json` and installs just fine if running it from it's own dedicated project. As I'm using setuptools to manage dependencies, would it make a difference if I downloaded it as a zipped egg vs. a simple directory layout?

---

Initially, it seems that my JSON wasn't being included in the egg, and this is why `syncdb` didn't work. Now, I've fixed that problem, but `syncdb` is *still* failing to find any of my fixtures. You can download the egg to see for yourself [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=django-locality&version=0.1.1). I can't think of any reason why Django would be missing the initial data. You can also [view the repository](http://github.com/rfkrocktk/django-locality) on GitHub. Why isn't Django seeing the fixtures?

---

When I run `syncdb -v 2`, I do see that Django sees the egg and looks for the fixtures:

```
No json fixture 'initial_data' in '/home/rfkrocktk/Desktop/myproject/eggs/django_locality-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/locality/fixtures'.
```

Is it possible that Django doesn't know how to read from eggs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as it turns out, Django *doesn't know how to look inside zipped egg files.* As soon as I extracted the egg file to a directory with its name, things worked.

Comment: update your question rather than writing questions in an answer :) !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your setup.py does not include the initial_data.json as package_data: http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data This means when you install from PyPi you won't get the initial_data.json file in your distribution.

I personally find it easier to use source distributions `sdist` for Django apps. In that case you can list non-Python files which need to be included in the MANIFEST: http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html

Comment: So in my example, what should I do? I've tried including a MANIFEST and have tried adding package data to my setup file, but it's still not including it.

Comment: It still seems like it's not working. I've determined that it's working; it's including the fixtures directory and json in the egg, but it's still not including it when running syncdb.