# Specify that packages should be automatically unzipped

Tags: python, setuptools, buildout

I [just ran into a weird issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319218/128967) where Django is unable to look inside of zipped egg files when searching for fixtures. I've noticed that in my project's `eggs` folder, *some* projects are unzipped to directories and some are left in their zip files. Is there a way for me to specify in `setup.py` that my project must be unzipped before use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TK, there is. Use the `zip_safe` parameter to the `setup()` method to tell setup that your file needs to be unzipped:

```
setup(
    ...
    zip_safe = False,
    ...
)
```