# How do I load fixtures from third-party app for django in tests?

Tags: django, testing, fixtures

I know fixtures can be loaded in the tests.py like this:

```
fixtures = ['example.json']
```

Django automatically search all the apps' fixture directory and load the fixtures.

However, I create a reusable app named `accounts` and in `accounts` I also have the `fixtures/example.json` file. But when I installed the `accounts` app and write it into the `INSTALLED_APP` settings, the fixture cannot be loaded. I am curious why it happens.

Django == 1.8.2

Comment: is your reusable app installed via `setup.py` and outside the project root?  if so you should check if the fixture is actually being installed in your app package http://stackoverflow.com/a/8318029/202168

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to load those fixtures if:

1. Your app fixtures are accessible, if the app is in the same project structure they are directly accessible
2. If the app is installed by **setup.py** the files should be included with `package_data={'mypkg': ['fixtures/*.json']}` depending on your configuration
3. You have to know where your **virtualenv** is located in the local system, this way you can tell Django in **settings** where fixtures are located, *imagine virtualenv is located in parent directory from project*, you can point to fixtures like this:

> Settings.py:

```
ENV_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(VENV_DIR, "virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yourapp/test/fixtures"),
)
```

Note that it will depends on local system, not a clean solution, but it works, pay attention if you are running tests on remote systems like jenkins because you'll have to change this configuration according to the server deployment settings.

Comment: See [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#data-files-support) for different ways to include "data" files.

Comment: This is an answer from 2015, there must be like a 1000 new ways to do it! I'm getting old

Comment: No, your answer is still applicable and very relevant. Actually I should have written "various" instead of "different".